# how do i distinguish between text for file name and test for analysis

Tags: java

I have here a program which is supposed to read in a file and calculate the density of the text within the file and then display the results in a chart. So far it works when entering text but when I have tried to make it so it reads in a file I'm getting an error with the buffered reader (I have put *'s on the line of the error) and also I'm having problems getting it to analyse the text in the file as it analysis the file name instead.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;
public class assignment
{
    static boolean drawn = false;
    static final int num = 4;
    BufferedReader bf = null;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("please enter a file name");
        String filename = in.nextLine();
        *bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));* 
        String[] data = {filename};
        diagram(data);
        in.close();
    }

    public static void diagram(String[] lines)
    {
        Map<Character, Integer> words = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

        for(String l : lines)
        {
            for(String w : l.split("\\s+"))
                for(char c : w.trim().toCharArray())                
                    if(words.containsKey(c))
                        words.put(c, words.get(c) + 1);
                    else
                        words.put(c, 1);
        }

        //first the most occuring then the printing
        words.forEach(new BiConsumer<Character, Integer>(){
            int i;

            @Override
            public void accept(Character t, Integer u)
            {
                if(u > i){
                    i = u;
                    rdraw(words, i);
                }
            }

        });
    }

    private static void rdraw(Map<Character, Integer> words, final int l)
    {
        if(drawn)
            return;

        words.forEach(new BiConsumer<Character, Integer>(){

            @Override
            public void accept(Character t, Integer u)
            {
                System.out.print(t + ": ");
                double d = (u * num)/l; 
                for(int i = 0; i < (int)d; i++)
                    System.out.print("=");
                System.out.println();
            }

        });

        drawn = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where you ask for the filename, you need to specify the exact path to the file, for windows that would be a syntax of `C:\\temp\\text.txt`

Comment: What error are you getting? Post the comlete stack trace of exception.

Comment: thankyou, but i do input the path for the file name from the user input prompt. thats all but in to the filename variable, that dosent explain why the bf in bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename)); has an error :s

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read a file you should do it as follows:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("please enter a file name");
String filename = in.nextLine();
in.close();
File file = new File(filename);
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList(); // Cant use a regular array because the length is unknown.
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    list.add(line);
}
br.close();
```

Now you have an arraylist that should contain all the lines from the file and you can work with that.

Comment: from the question, the problem is when trying to open the file, so it still isn't what you're answering (thought Alex Davies will need your answer as soon as he's able to open the file)

Comment: @dtortola from the question `*bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));*` if the error occurs here, as mentioned, then the only thing that can be wrong is an incorrect path to the file. Since that is being obtained by user input... i tried it myself, it's working fine as long as the path is specified like it should. `C:\\temp\\t.txt` for files not in the project working directory, `t.txt` if the file is in the working directory of the project.

Comment: @dtortola the acual thing being wrong is that `BufferedReader bf = null;` is declared outside of the static context of the main method, it should be declared as `static BufferedReader bf = null;`

Comment: @WonderWorld you're right, I overlooked that. But then the problem is compile time

Comment: @dtortola since `String[] data = {filename};` wouldn't have gotten any result like it should, i decided to post a working solution. To be honest i overlooked the `static` part as well until your comment. :)